# how to update my github library with an existing fork?

Tags: github

my friend forked my library and worked on it, but the old version appears on my Github page.  Now can I show the new master?

[image]

Comment: Your friend can open a pull request.

Comment: See also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148003/pulling-in-changes-from-a-forked-repo-without-a-request-on-github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend must create a `pull request`.

You have to merge these `pull requests` with your master once you have reviewed them.

If the merge is successful, it'll show the new master.